# Splitting text file in Python - delimeter issue

Tags: python-3.x, file, split

I try to split a file by delimeter: `"}.`, but the delimeter is not found and as a result I get only one new file with the same content as the original one. The code is:

```py
with  open('okladki_200_01') as fp:
    contents = fp.read()

    i = 1
    for entry in contents.split('"}.'):

        f= open("okladka_%s" % i,"w+")
        f.write(entry)
        f.close()
        i += 1
```

Can you help, please?

EDIT:
The content of the file is like:

```
{"base64Image":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAusFMADASIA\nAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAgIBBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAgQAAwUBBgcICQoL/8QAaRAAAQEFBAcDBwgHBQYD\nAwEZAwIBBBESEwAhIiMFFDEyM0FDUVNhBiRCY3GBkQcIFTRSc6GxRGKDk8HR8FRyo+HxCRYlZLPD\ndILTFzWEkp [...] 3aIiVoL1pmNQxjWr27\nPBnhatT94NfdwDzDBz9aSP/Z\n","elementHashcode":-1794239528,"imageOrientation":6,"type":"BOOK"}
{"base64Image":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
```

And I think I just found the problem... HxD viewer displays 0x0A ASCII character as a dot, but it is New Line. So I should look for `'"}\n'`

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the file, so we can verify what's going wrong?

Comment: You have an indentation issue at line 2 and the last `fp.close()` is redundant with the `with`. No need to close the file twice.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy this is the example file (30 MB) http://www.filedropper.com/okladki30001

Comment: have you tried '''"}.''' ?

Answer (score 0):

Move contents.split('"}.') into its own variable.

```
lines = contents.split('.}"')

for entry in lines: 
    ...
```

Code :

```
with  open('textfile') as fp:
    contents = fp.read()

i = 1

lines = contents.split('.}"')

for entry in lines: 
    f= open("textfile_%s" % i,"w+")
    f.write(entry)
    f.close()
    i += 1

fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to check for brackets? In your case it seems like your input file is already formatted with 1 content = 1 line, so our delimiter could be `\n` instead and we can use `readlines()`.

Here is a possible solution:

```
with  open('okladki_200_01') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines() # this is a list of strings.

    i = 1
    for line in lines:
        entry = line.lstrip("{").rstrip("}\n") # some clean-up.
        f = open("okladka_%s" %i ,"w+")
        f.write(entry)
        f.close()
        i += 1
```